# "Unsupported huge granule pos -123480" when trying to convert from .opus extracted from Video to .wav using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, opus

I have to convert a bunch of .opus files to .wav using ffmpeg. When calling

`ffmpeg -i input_file.opus -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output_file.wav`

I get

`Unsupported huge granule pos -123480`

This does not depend on the specific ffmpeg options. An example .opus file can be found [here](https://bwsyncandshare.kit.edu/dl/fiSnnNTyXzJiZhGeNothDTqV/053oq2xB3oU.opus). The .opus file is a part of a soundstream extracted from a youtube video in .mkv container format with .opus as audio stream with the highest available quality. The corresponding ffmpeg call was

`ffmpeg -ss 00:15:00.00 -i input_file.mkv -to 00:15:00.00 -vn -acodec copy output_file.opus`

The line raising the original exception is

`if (os->granule > (1LL << 62)) 
     {av_log(avf, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Unsupported huge granule pos %"PRId64 "\n", os->granule);
     return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
    }`

It can be found in lines 121-124 of [this](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/oggparseopus.c) file. `granule` is defined as an uint_64t [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/oggdec.h).

So, what I figured so far is that a uint probably shouldn't be negative after all. I'm unsure whether the error is occuring during the extraction of the audio but remains unnoticed until trying to convert said audio or if the error is in the actual conversion. I also do not understand what "granule" is supposed to mean in this context, but probably I don't need to.

Comment: opusinfo shows the same error for the example file, and opusdec fails to convert the file too. I suggest you redownload or download another format.

Comment: Unfortunately redownloading isn't possible as not all required videos are still available on Youtube. If I do not copy the stream from the original file but reencode it(-acodec libopus instead of -acodec copy) I do not encounter this problem but the bitrate of the output file drops from 119 kb/s to 83 kb/s. This is somewhat unsatisfying but will have to do for the moment.

Comment: *"The .opus file is a part of a soundstream extracted from a youtube video"* How did you download the file? I recommend reviewing your method or trying an alternative method to see if this is the point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Are these Ogg Opus files or are the Opus audio packets encapsulated in another container?  Try using [MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html) to extract the audio stream.

The *.opus URL you provided requires authentication and I cannot access.

Comment: Thanks for still caring about this question and sorry for the inaccessible file, I thought I had configured the link correctly. I actually just went with reencoding the audio at extraction time, avoiding the error. So for the moment this problem has very low priority.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the wav file from the mkv without the intermediate opus file:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:15:00.00 -i input_file.mkv -to 00:15:00.00 -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output_file.wav
```

Alternatively, try splitting off the full opus file from the original mkv before extracting the portion that you're interested in:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mkv -vn -acodec copy input_file.opus
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:15:00 -i input_file.opus -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output_file.wav
```

I've seen these "Unsupported huge granule pos ...." errors when extracting from youtube sourced opus content.
What has worked for me so far is to have ffmpeg "re-write" the full opus bitstream before extracting portions of it:

```
ffmpeg -i from_youtube.opus -codec copy dupe.opus
ffmpeg -ss 00:15:00.000 -to 00:25:00 -i dupe.opus -codec copy extract.opus
```

Seems that ffmpeg can have problems trying to extract sections from youtube produced opus bitstreams.